# About Locally Compact Groups and Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, locally-compact-groups

This question was asked in my previous Ph.D. qualifying for Analysis and I couldn't solve it. I have no clue on how to proceed.

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and let $f \in C_c(G)$ where $C_c(G)$ is the set of all continuous functions on $G$ with compact supports. Then $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there is an open neighborhood  $U$ of the identity such that whenever $y \in xU$, it follows that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

What is the identity? what is a locally compact group? and what they mean for $xU$ ? a very odd problem for an analysis qualifying.

Comment: All the relevant definitions can be found on, say, Wikipedia. In the end, the problem boils down to showing that every continuous function on a compact space is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Wow... that was a low blow. Now I see it. I know how to prove that one.

Comment: Probably you realize this,  but note that $C_c(G)$ is the space of _continuous_ functions with compact support...